# randomly sample rows of a dataframe until the desired sum of a column is reached

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID  key   acres
1   156   10
2   157   60
3   158   50
4   159   1
5   160   9
6   161   110
```

and I want to randomly select rows until the sum of the selected `acres` from each sampled row reaches 150, or is as close to 150 as possible. I want to store the 'ID' of all the rows that are selected.

I am currently trying to do this:

```
acres = 0
obid = []
while acres <= 150:
     rows = random.sample(df.index, 1)
     sample= df.ix[rows]
     acres = acres + sample['acres']
     obid.append(sample['ID'])
     df= df.drop(rows)
```

but there are a couple problems with this approach.  First, it is possible that the same rows are sampled twice since I am dropping the samples within the loop, and not actually changing the original df.  Second, I get this error returned:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

This leads me to believe there is a better approach entirely.

Comment: You could end up in a situation where you have all of the displayed rows selected by the random draw.  If `ID==6` is drawn last, then you will have a sum of acres 240.  Is this ok?

Comment: Yes I can work with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try something like this:

- `sample` pulls a sample row from the dataframe, argument `frac=1` states get 100% of
  the rows. This basically shuffles the dataframe.
- Use `iterrrows` to iterate through the shuffled dataframe.

Code:

```
acres = 0
obid = []
for i in df.sample(frac=1).iterrows():
    if (acres + i[1]['acres']) <= 150:
        acres += i[1]['acres']
        obid.append(i[1]['ID'])

print(obid)
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 4, 1]
```

Let's look at the original dataframe with results

```
 print(df[df['ID'].isin(obid)])
```

Output:

```
   ID  key  acres
0   1  156     10
3   4  159      1
4   5  160      9
5   6  161    110
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short version.

```
df_shuffled = df.sample(frac = 1) #shuffle data
df_shuffled[df_shuffled.acres.cumsum() <= 150]['ID']
```

The second line makes a column of cumsum, then filters it using '<= 150', for example:

| ID | Key | acres | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 158 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 157 | 60 | 110 |
| 1 | 156 | 10 | 120 |
| 6 | 161 | 110 | 230 |
| 5 | 160 | 9 | 239 |
| 4 | 159 | 1 | 240 |

Which gets filtered down to:

| ID | Key | acres | cumsum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 158 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 157 | 60 | 110 |
| 1 | 156 | 10 | 120 |