# Python: how randomly revert entries in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called `randomNet` which contains the columns `home`, `work`, `hi`, `wi`, `hj`, `wj`. I want to randomly change the entries by selecting random rows. This is what I am doing, but I am not sure it is a good solution.

```
for i in randomNet.index:
    tmp = rand()
    if tmp > 0.5:
        h  =  randomNet.home[i]
        w  =  randomNet.work[i]
        hi = randomNet.hi[i]
        wi = randomNet.wi[i]
        hj = randomNet.hj[i]
        wj = randomNet.wj[i]
        randomNet.home[i] = w
        randomNet.work[i] = h
        randomNet.hi[i] = wi
        randomNet.wi[i] = hi
        randomNet.hj[i] = wj
        randomNet.wj[i] = hj
```

Comment: How about not actually shuffling the dataframe?  Can you instead select randoming for a dataframe?  See this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509114/randomly-sample-rows-of-a-dataframe-until-the-desired-sum-of-a-column-is-reached/43509681#43509681) using df.sample(frac=1).

Comment: Are you trying to get a random row, a dataframe back with the rows randomly shuffled, a dataframe with values shuffled randomly within each column, or something else?

Comment: If the second, df.sample(frac=1) as suggested by @Scott works. If the first, df.sample() or df.sample(n=1).