# Python: Select random rows from a dataframe for which the sum of a specific column equals X

Tags: python, sql, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

```
  class number_of_lessons
0   C   15
1   A   5
2   B   8
3   E   11
4   N   12
5   F   5
6   D   10
```

I want to randomly select some rows from this table such as the sum of number of lessons in the new dataframe equals to 20.

As an example of output, we can have:

```
   class number_of_lessons
0   C   15
1   A   5
```

or

```
class number_of_lessons
1   A   5
5   F   5
6   D   10
```

I tried too many things but nothing was correct. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [randomly sample rows of a dataframe until the desired sum of a column is reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43509114/randomly-sample-rows-of-a-dataframe-until-the-desired-sum-of-a-column-is-reached)

Comment: Did you try [subset sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23087820/python-subset-sum) and then index by those elements that made the sum?

Comment: Totally @Sushanth thank you; I just added an "while ((iteration<50) & (acres<20)):" before the suggested solution so that it stops when I have exactly a sum of 20

Answer (score 0):

Try with the next code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['C', 'A', 'B', 'E', 'N', 'F', 'D'],  'number_of_lessons':[15, 5, 8, 11, 12, 5, 10]})

classes = []
lessons = 0
for i in df.sample(frac=1).iterrows():
    if (lessons + i[1]['number_of_lessons']) <= 20:
        lessons += i[1]['number_of_lessons']
        classes.append(i[1]['class'])
    if lessons == 20:
        break

print(df[df['class'].isin(classes)])
```

Output:

```
  class  number_of_lessons
2     B                  8
4     N                 12
```

Comment: Did this approach fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach that you could loop until you get exactly 20.

```
df_new = df
while df_new.number_of_lessons.sum() != 20:
    df_shuffled = df.sample(frac = 1) #shuffle data
    new_df = df_shuffled[df_shuffled.numer_of_lessons.cumsum() <= 20]
```

The second line makes a column of cumsum, then filters it using '<= 20'.